# MVC 4 - PK-Restriction insulted with derived classes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, private-key

This is my setup:

- Base class "Asset" with property "ID"
- Derived classes "Bond", "Future".

I'm using table per type. Now, I when creating the 2nd Bond / Future, this exception is thrown on db.SaveChanges():

```
An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships.
```

with detailed description stating that the Primary-Key restriction of table Bond was insulted (the key exists already).

The first entry in table bond has an ID of 0, so something is obviously wrong with the Primary Key.

I've tried the following:

- Base class "Asset" with property ID, Derived classes "Bond" & "Future" without extra property IDs.
- Base class "Asset" with property ID, Derived classes "Bond" & "Future" with extra property IDs.
- Base class "Asset" without property ID, Derived classes "Bond" & "Future" with extra property IDs.
- adding "[KEY]"
- naming they ID not ID but BondID, FutureID

and have dropped and setup the database before testing each of these, but the exception is the same.

Other entities in my setup successfully get automatic and correct primary keys. I dont see what is wrong here.. **How do I get correct primary keys?** Thank you for any advice!

Comment: In SQL Server Management Studio, I see that the table seems to be set up correct with column "ID" being set as PK, int, not null ...

Comment: Does the ID column have an Identity Specification, or are you setting the primary key values yourself? (Just wondering, because the fact that the first row has an ID of 0 indicates the opposite, you're not setting the primary key values yourself and the ID doesn't have an Identity Specification)